# How to pip or easy_install tkinter on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pip, easy-install

IDLE is throwing errors that and says `tkinter` can't be imported.

Is there a simple way to install `tkinter` via `pip` or `easy_install`?

There seem to be a lot of package names flying around for this...

This and other assorted variations with `tkinter-pypy` aren't working.
This is what I run:

```
pip install python-tk
```

I'm on Windows with Python 2.7 and I don't have `apt-get` or other system package managers.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well I can see two solutions here:

***1) Follow the [Docs-Tkinter install for Python](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) ([for Windows](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin)):***

Tkinter (and, since Python 3.1, ttk) are included with all standard Python distributions. It is important that you use a version of Python supporting Tk 8.5 or greater, and ttk. We recommend installing the "ActivePython" distribution from ActiveState, which includes everything you'll need.

In your web browser, go to [Activestate.com](http://www.activestate.com), and follow along the links to download the Community Edition of ActivePython for Windows. Make sure you're downloading a 3.1 or newer version, not a 2.x version.

Run the installer, and follow along. You'll end up with a fresh install of ActivePython, located in, e.g. `C:\python32`. From a Windows command prompt, or the Start Menu's "Run..." command, you should then be able to run a Python shell via:

```
% C:\python32\python
```

This should give you the Python command prompt. From the prompt, enter these two commands:

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```

This should pop up a small window; the first line at the top of the window should say "This is Tcl/Tk version 8.5"; make sure it is not 8.4!

***2) Uninstall 64-bit Python and install 32 bit Python.***

Comment: for import _tkinter I get:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: Python 2.7.5 on 64 bit

Comment: For python 3 the current version is 8.6

Answer (score 123):

The Tkinter library is built-in with every Python installation. And since you are on Windows, I believe you installed Python through the binaries on their website?

If so, Then most probably you are typing the command wrong. It should be:

```py
import Tkinter as tk
```

Note the capital T at the beginning of Tkinter.

For Python 3,

```py
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: import Tkinter as tk gets: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 38, in <module>
    import FixTk
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FixTk.py", line 65, in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: For the import statement: Python 2.* uses Tkinter with capital 'T', Python 3.*: uses tkinter with small 't'.

Comment: This works for me on Windows 10 and python 3.7.0 on 64 bit

Comment: Easy and Better answer @IcyFlame

Answer (score 55):

If you are using virtualenv, it is fine to install tkinter using `sudo apt-get install python-tk`(python2), `sudo apt-get install python3-tk`(python3), and and it will work fine in the virtual environment

Comment: But this doesn't work if we don't have sudo access and are inside our own virtualenv.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install python-tk" worked for me WHILE inside my virtualenv and fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't answer the question since the OP is working on windows. The answer belongs to a linux question.

Answer (score 27):

When installing make sure that under `Tcl/Tk` you select `Will be installed on hard drive`.  If it is installing with a cross at the left then Tkinter will not be installed.

[image]

The same goes for Python 3:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this reminder! I'd completely forgotten those two were coupled.

Comment: This is the actually correct answer for OP's use case.

Answer (score 19):

When you install python for Windows, use the standard option or install everything it asks. I got the error because I deselected tcl.

Comment: That's it! I deselected "tk/tcl and IDLE" option during installation because I didn't want IDLE. I reinstalled python and tkinter is detected.

Comment: If this is the case, tkinter can be added by modifying the installation and ticking tk/tcl

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for an answer to this same question and none of the answers above actually answer the question at all!

So after some investigation I found out:
there is a package (for python 3.x at least):

```
pip3 install pytk
```

The problem is, it is only the python part of the equation and doesn't install the tkinter libraries in your OS, so the answer is that you can't install it completely via pip
https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html

Personally I find this very annoying as i'm packaging a python application to be installed via pip that uses tkinter and I was looking for a way to have pip ensure that tkinter is installed and the answer is I can't I have to instruct users to install it if it's not installed already, a very poor experience for end users who should not need to know or care what tkinter is to use my application.

Comment: The [`pytk` package](https://pypi.org/project/pytk/) **does not** install anything relevant. It is **only** a wrapper designed to give a more Pythonic interface to the `tkinter` standard library (which is designed to mimic the Tcl/Tk interface).

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem in Linux. This solved it. (I'm on Debian 9 derived Bunsen Helium)

> $ sudo apt-get install python3-tk

Comment: This worked for me on my Ubuntu 18.04 server but why? Do linux python distributions not come with tkinter?

Comment: For a long time, they only came with Python 2.

Comment: Doesnt answer the question — OP is running Windows.

Answer (score 3):

In python, Tkinter was a default package, you can repair the installation and select Tcl/Tk. [image: repair] When you run this, DDL should be installed like so: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting as the top answer requotes the documentation which I didn't find  useful.

tkinter comes packaged with python install on windows IFF you select it during the install window.

The solution is to repair the installation (via uninstall GUI is fine), and select to install tk this time. You may need to point at or redownload the binary in this process. Downloading directly from activestate did not work for me.

This is a common problem people have on windows as it's easy to not want to install TCL/TK if you don't know what it is, but Matplotlib etc require it.

Comment: FWIW, matplotlib can be used with PyQt5 (and several other graphics backends) instead of tkinter, and PyQt5 is neatly and completely installable via `pip install pyqt5`.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to upgrade my tkinter from the python built-in and found this method useful:

```
conda install -c anaconda tk
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem with Win-8 and python-3.4 32 bit , I got it resolved by downloading same version from python.org .

Next step will be to hit the repair button and Install the Tk/tkinter Package or Just hit the repair.
Now  should get Python34/Lib/tkinter Module present.
The import tkinter should work  ..

Answer (score -3):

Easiest way to do this:

```
cd C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts> 
pip install pythonds
```

[image: Screenshot of installing]

Comment: code on your screenshot is not the code you've added

Answer (score -5):

Inside `cmd`, run command `pip install tk` and Tkinter should install.

Comment: I did this on Ubuntu and it installed TensorKit, a library related to deep learning.

Comment: Yep, it's *not* tkinter. https://pypi.org/project/tk/

Answer (score -7):

if your using python 3.4.1 just write this line `from tkinter import *` this will put  everything in the module into the default namespace of your program. in fact instead of referring to say a button like `tkinter.Button` you just type `Button`

Comment: from Tkinter import *

Comment: The question is asking about how to _install_ tkinter, not how to import it into a program.