# Can't import tkinter (or Tkinter)

Tags: python, import, tkinter

I am trying to import Tkinter to my project using Python 2.7 and instead I get the error:

> ImportError: No module named tkinter

Before anyone says it, I have tried both "Tkinter" and "tkinter" but have gotten the exact same message.

Comment: Then Tkinter isn't available on your system. Are you using your system's built-in installation of Python, which may not include Tcl or Tkinter?

Comment: I believe so but I was sure I installed Tcl and Tkinter

Comment: Try to install the tk-python package and check this again. For windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter or for linux http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python

Comment: read a little documentation, search this site. You'll find that the name of tkinter has changed between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: @BryanOakley he said he tried both `tkinter` and `Tkinter`. Do you mean something different?

Comment: Which OS, python version, and installer?

Comment: Impressive how the "Before anyone says it, I have tried both "Tkinter" and "tkinter" but have gotten the exact same message" part was in the original version of the question, but almost everyone ignored that in order to propose changing the spelling, using wrapper code to try both spellings etc.

Answer (score 11):

First try using this code for your imports.

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk # this is for python2
except:
    import tkinter as tk # this is for python3
```

If this doesn't work, try reinstalling tkinter. If you don't know how to reinstall tkinter look at the tkinter installation page, [here.](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ubuntu or Debian OS try this:-

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

Or if you are using Python 3:-

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Answer (score 2):

Some compilers have tkinter preinstalled. For example, if you use IDLE tkinter is preinstalled. As much as I know, if you use IDLE, you have to click a box in order to install tkinter.
If you are not using IDLE, check whether tkinter/Tkinter is included in your Site Packages folder. Consider reinstalling the compiler/interpreter you are using.
After you made sure it is installed the syntax you have to use depends on the version of Python you are using.
I am not quite sure for Python 2, but I think you write:

```
import Tkinter
```

For Python 3 you write:

```
import tkinter
```

or the more often used:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Answer (score 2):

if you install Python 3.7 you will need to type this:

```
from tkinter import *
```

then you can use tkinter.

Answer (score 2):

For **Python 2** use this:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

For **Python 3** use this:

```
from tkinter import *
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem ,please try this;

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Comment: Some times this doesn't work because you need to import it `as` something

Answer (score 0):

Just try this, it's working on python 3.7

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import simpledialog
    ROOT = tk.Tk()
    ROOT.withdraw()
    # the input dialog
    Uname= simpledialog.askstring(title="Hey Buddy",
                              prompt="Will you 
    please enter your good name")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should install the `tkinter` package for python. **Tkinter** has been renamed to **tkinter** in Python 3. The `2to3` tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Note: The following commands below are assuming that you run Debian or Ubuntu:

For Python 2:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

for Python 3:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```