# No module named tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So last night I tried to start working with tkinter, and I sifted through several articles and youtube videos on how to install it. I (thought) installed it through brew, as well as a package download of activeTCL. I am just trying to make a simple program. this is all it is:

```
from tkinter import *

root = tk()

label1 = Label(root, text = "tkiner test")
label1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But, when I run it in terminal, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copmeter.py", line 1, in 
    from tkinter import *
ImportError: No module named tkinter

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? or what I have to do exactly to install tkinter? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using python 2? If so, the module is called `Tkinter` with a capital T.

Comment: I tried that too. Still get the same error. Lol I have no idea what im doing wrong

Comment: Do you see tkinter in the output of the "brew list" command?

Comment: I see tcl-tk, but not tkinter

Comment: That's the problem - it seems like tkinter has not been installed (properly). Try reinstalling.

Comment: can u explain how to install it? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Read this thread. It might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36760839/why-my-python-installed-via-home-brew-not-include-tkinter

Comment: Still not working. This makes no sense. whatever. ill find something else to try a GUI with python

Comment: Related: [How to pip or easy_install tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20044559/3357935)

Comment: It looks like you are using python 2  
In python 2, use `from Tkinter import *`   
In python 3, use `from tkinter import *`   
**Reference:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822599/7280140