# tkinter not found in python-3.8 while it is working in python-3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I just installed python-3.8.3 on ubuntu. while tkinter was working on python-3.5, I am getting error  *import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'*  on python-3.8.3.  I did sudo apt-get install python3-tk, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install tkinter for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114470/12977390

oh... may be you should try with:

> sudo apt install python3-tkinter

i do use fedora linux, and python3-tk does't work, but '-tkinter' do.
tell me if was successful