# How to resolve import matplotlib.pyplot as plt error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am having trouble getting my matplotlib library to work. I am running it on a virual environment, and I have installed numpy, and matplotlib. I first open my virtual environment, activate python, then I enter,

```
import matplotlib
```

everything goes fine, but then I enter,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get the error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "/Users/kendallreid/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
```

I have tried a number of different solutions to no avail. What could be the problem?

Comment: for python < 3.1 -> `pip install tkinter` - You may want to check http://stackoverflow.com/q/20044559/797495

Comment: Try this :
`import matplotlib`
`matplotlib.use('Agg')`
`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Answer (score 2):

Use the below mentioned commands:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use(‘TkAgg’)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

This worked for me. I hope it helps.