# ImportError: No module named _tkinter in Python 2.7.13

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, module, importerror

I am running RedHat 4.1.2 offline and trying to get _tkinter working for Python 2.7.13. I have Tcl/tk 8.4 installed, but it doesn't seem to be working right. libtcl8.4.so is located in /usr/lib64/ and I'm not sure if that's related, but I figured I would mention it. Here is the error when I try import Tkinter.

[Python terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J37zX.png)

Comment: Tcl 8.4 might not be good enough to support Tkinter. However, simply installing Tcl (or having it already installed) is *definitely* not good enough. Tkinter is two more layers sitting on top of that: the `tkinter` Python code (which you have), and the `_tkinter` C library (which you don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could try a package manager such as Anaconda and install Tkinter.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter#20044745) may help.

Comment: I'm offline, so installing a package manager doesn't help and I can't use apt-get or wget. I am transferring tar files from my windows machine to the linux machine

Comment: Is your machine virtualised?

Comment: I'm ssh'd into the server. but can transfer files to my home directory from Windows

Comment: Download an offline installer for Anaconda. A simple google search should lead you to it.

Comment: So I installed it, but I'm still having the same error

Comment: Can you share the output of '$which python'

Comment: "Python 2.7.13 (default, Jun  7 2017, 14:35:11)" And then it starts the python interpreter

Comment: Then it's not the Anaconda python. You'll have to update PYTHON_PATH and PATH environment variables to point to your installation. Set your python to Anaconda python interpreter