# No module named 'tkinter'

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

First of all, I am using Windows 10 and python 3.7.4.
When I try to `import tkinter`, I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`.
How can I install tkinter? I thought it should come with the default python installation. Can I use `pip` somehow?

I get that many people already made posts about this error, but they all seem to either work on Linux and solve it with `sudo apt-get install python3-tk` or accidentally write `Tkinter`, which are both not my case.

Comment: Tkinter already comes with Python. Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows)? If it doesn't, uninstall and reinstall Python and see for Tkinter checkbox: I think there was one.

Comment: How did you install your Python?

Comment: No, you cannot use Pip. Instead, reinstall Python or "repair" the installation, and this time, choose to include Tcl/Tk and IDLE. See the linked duplicate for details.