# how to install tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

i have seen many such previously asked questions , and i have seen many pages explaining how to install this  , but i see i am too beginner , so i dont know where to write this

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

is this to be written in the python terminal that is python.exe , or in the cmd can somebody help me i am new to python but i know basics of programming in c++ and java
if i write this in cmd - here i get this

```
C:\Users\shaurya>sudo apt-get install python-tk  'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or externalcommand ,operable program or batch file.
```

inside the python terminal -  `sudo apt-get install python-tkFile "<stdin>", line 1 sudo apt-get install python-tk     syntax error ^`

Comment: Under Windows, you need to select `tkinter` when installing Python.  The command you posted is for Linux systems.

Comment: can you please tell me the command for windows

Comment: It is not a command.  It is one of the option to include `tkinter` when installing Python.

Comment: check my answer. You must have messed up while installing Tkinter. You don't have to install Tkinter in order to use it. It comes with your Python installation.

Comment: Here is a related question https://stackoverflow.com/q/20044559/5607735. This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is inbuilt in Python

You should use pip for installing modules

You should use cmd to type in any pip commands

for example:-

```
  pip install "module_name"
```

enter the module name without the quotes

Comment: pip is not recognized

Comment: Did you add pip to your PATH system variable?

Comment: If not [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708898/pip-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: Not sure, but I guess you have to use `python -m pip install module-name`.

Comment: @SHikhaMittal please make sure if pip is installed in your system. If it is not installed please check this out: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#id10

Comment: I use pip everyday, if u add pip to your PATH system variable you could directly start from pip without typing "python -m"

Answer (score -2):

Okay, so here's what you need to do. Use the control panel to uninstall your python and then install the latest version. Write this code in any IDE to verify your python and Tkinter installation:

```
from tkinter import *
print("Success!")
```

https://www.python.org/downloads/