# no module named 'Tkinter' on windows

Tags: python, tkinter

i'm using windows pc. It appears Tkinter doesn't come with the installation.

```
python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

So i've tried to install it with pip.

```
pip install tk
Collecting tk
  Using cached tk-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Installing collected packages: tk
Successfully installed tk-0.1.0
```

When i try to import;

```
import Tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'
```

or

```
import tkinter
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

Comment: If python pre-installed, Tkinter actually comes along when we install Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows try `pip install python-tk` but it seems like Tobi208s answer is the solution

Comment: tkinter cannot be installed using `pip`.  It is an option when installing Python in Windows.

Comment: i've tried uninstall and reinstall. didn't work.

Comment: The package `tk` is _not_ tkinter. You can't install tkinter with pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the option `tcl/tk and IDLE` when installing Python on Windows. Retroactive installation through `pip` doesn't work.

Comment: yes i didn't want the IDLE so i didn't check the option. But that means i have to install python again?

Comment: Yep, it's annoying, I know.

Comment: @ghost21blade they already did that as stated in their question

Comment: @ghost21blade I've already tried. Didn't work

Comment: well you don't have to re-install python. In my case i just downloaded windows executable installer and there is modify option. you can just install tk ıdle from there.

Comment: Awesome, good to know

Comment: @ghost21blade: that `tk` that is installable by pip isn't tkinter. It's some other package.