# how to fix the error that ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm, remote-server

I connected to the remote server (google cloud VM instance - Centos7) with PyCharm from my Windows computer and wanted to execute the code using the remote computer's python3.8.8 via PyCharm. However, I got the error that says

**File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 36, in**

**import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk**

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'**

I tried to do some different pip installs (pip install python3-tkinter, pip install python3-tk, pip install python3.8-tkinter, etc.) and output of

"pip install python3-tkinter" is

**Package python3-tkinter-3.6.8-18.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do.**

Is this tkinter for python3.6?

How can I fix this error?

Comment: why the underscore `_tkinter` ?  This link might be useful (i think i used it when installing the same):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows.

Comment: @D.L: `_tkinter` is a compiled module that is part of the tkinter package. It contains the low-level code that interfaces with the tcl/tk interpreter.

Comment: @BryanOakley:  thanks,  presumably this means that it is not installed on the host. I posted an answer, but you are welcome to edit or comment on it further.

Comment: Normally Python libraries are installed in `/usr/lib`, but the error is `/usr/local/lib`.  Where is the Python binary (use `which python3` to check)?

Comment: if you run code on `remote server` then you need `tkinter` installed on this server. But problem is that `tkinter` will try to run on server and display on monitor directly connected to server. And it will need `XWindows` on server to display windows. But servers usually don't have `XWindows` (because they don't need it - they don't even have monitors) and they may not have installed `tkinter` (because it can't be used without `XWindows` and monitor). As I remeber sometimes Ubuntu Servers may have installed `Python` without `tkitner`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does tkinter (or turtle) seem to be missing or broken? Shouldn't it be part of the standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105218/why-does-tkinter-or-turtle-seem-to-be-missing-or-broken-shouldnt-it-be-part)

Comment: "I tried to do some different pip installs" - Tkinter **cannot be installed with Pip**. If the Python you are trying to use is in /usr/local/lib, then it is not the system Python, meaning that system packages (e.g. `sudo apt-get python3-tk`) will also not fix the problem. You need to re-compile the Python in question with Tkinter support. Please see the linked duplicate for details.

Comment: Aside from that, remoting into another computer and expecting GUI libraries to work is a bit of a problem. First off - where are you expecting the window to show up?