# I am facing a 'name Tk is not defined' in VS code

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am using VS code for my python and I am getting an error saying

```
'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\thecodeadd\OneDrive\Documents\Program\Python\Pyton programs\Fidget spinner.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tkinter
  File "c:\Users\thecodeadd\OneDrive\Documents\Program\Python\Pyton programs\tkinter.py", line 2, in <module>
    win= Tk()
NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined'
```

I have repaired my python file and searched on the internet but I have not been able to find any solutions for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code.

Comment: Sounds like tkinter is not installed. I'm on linux and you are on windows so the install is different ... does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044559/how-to-pip-or-easy-install-tkinter-on-windows

Comment: Oh, I thought that it was alreeady instaled when you use python. Thank you!

Comment: Please attach your definition code for TK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't import the `Tk` class. Intead, you imported the `tkinter` module. To use the `Tk` class from the module you need to use `win = tkinter.Tk()`.

It also looks like you named your file `tkinter.py`, which means that even if you do the above it won't work because your `tkinter.py` will get imported instead of the tkinter module. You should rename your file to something else besides `tkinter.py`.

Comment: Thank you! I found the file in my workspace after searching for it